Was Igor Karkaroff headmaster of Durmstrang during the first time Voldemort was in power?
We know that Karkaroff was a death eater during the first wizarding war. But was he also teaching at Durmstrang during that time or did he joined the school after coming back from Azkaban during the time between the two wars?

Sirius sort of told Harry in the Gryffindor common room fire that Karkaroff started teaching after he came out of Azkaban and it's the only canon reference I can find, so looks like he became headmaster between the two wars.

"He did a deal with the Ministry of Magic," said Sirius bitterly. "He
said he'd seen the error of his ways, and then he named names...he put
a load of other people into Azkaban in his place....He's not very
popular in there, I can tell you. And since he got out, from what I
can tell, he's been teaching the Dark Arts to every student who passes
through that school of his. So watch out for the Durmstrang champion
as well."


Does "since he got out" imply that he hadn't been doing it before he got in? Alternatively, perhaps he was teaching beforehand, but only teaching the Dark Arts since getting out of Azkaban.
